# Cluster utilization per user HDP

Tags: hadoop, performance-testing, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a application running on HDP cluster I need to collect stats which user is using how much CPU, can someone please advise where can I get this information ?

Like last 24 hour , 1 hour etc.